# Building a ranking (biased) score function

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Lets say I have the following table

```
id,  s1,  s2,  s3, r1, r2, r3

01, 0.5, 0.6, 0.4,  4,  3,  6
02, 0.2, 0.8, 0.3,  8,  1,  7
```

Where id is just an item id. s1-s3 is the score of algorithm 1-3 and r1-r3 is their rank in that algorithm. Meaning if id 01 have `s2 = 0.6` it gets `r2 = 3` and if id 02 have `s2 = 0.8` which is better it gets `r2 = 1` meaning algorithm 2 ranked it at the top.

I want to build a function which will use all of the above columns to calculate a score for the items to determine which item is better. Where a high score is better then low score. and low rank (1) is better then high rank (5). But I want to force the first 2 positions to belong into algorithm 1 (which i have data on him with s1 and r1). I want to force the next 8 positions to belong to algorithm 2. I want to force the next 10 items to algorithm 3 and then force the rest of the items to algorithm 2.

Please let me know how to clarify my question if its not understood.

To be more precise, the function will generate scores for all items. Lets say it'll generate scores for 200 items. I want the best 2 scores will be gives to items that have rank 1 and 2 in r1. I want the next 8 scores to be rank 1-8 in r2. I want the next 10 ranks after to be rank 1-10 in r3 and the next 180 scores to be rank 9-189 in r2

Comment: I don't think this is clear.  What does "I want to force the first $2$ positions to belong into algorithm $1$" mean?  Positions in what?  What does it mean to belong into an algorithm?

Comment: More broadly, it's going to be hard for anyone to work with this kind of information.  There are too many unknowns.   Suppose I get a bad score under some algorithm but I am the highest ranked item in that category.  How should I evaluate that?  That won't have an objective answer...you'll have to decide how to rescale the rankings.

Comment: That's exactly how you've understood it. This ranking system will rank up 200 items. When I say I want to preserve the first 2 spots for algorithm 1 I mean that the function generate scores to the items and the best 2 scores will belong to algorithm 1 no matter how low their score is by s1, as long as they ranked 1, 2 by r1.

Comment: I think you need to spell this out in greater detail.  Don't do it in the comments, write it out in the post. Like I said, there are a lot of subjective choices that need to be made when you are comparing different ranking schemes...a very much doubt that anyone can come up with an objective blending that satisfies all (unspecified) requirements.

Comment: You are right. Does the above clarify the ranking ?

Comment: Well, the rules you specify appear to self-contradict.  Suppose one item ranks first in both $s_1,s_2$.  then you appear to assign it global rank $1$ and $3$.

Comment: Not exactly. I will handle those repetition of items on my own. According to the above scheme I want that in position 1 (the best score) I will have item x. with score sx and in position 3 i will have item x again but with a score sy where sx > sy.

Comment: Once again, the issue is that there are lots of subjective choices to be made.  Sure, you can come up with a scheme to resolve conflicts...so can I, so can anyone.  But there's no apparent mathematically distinguished way to proceed.  Anyway, it sounds like you have a full scheme in mind.  Why not use that one?

Comment: Because of implementation problems. I need to achieve all that in 1 formula. I have a much better way to solve that (even greater) problem but the implementation abilities we have restrict me for now. :<

Comment: Ok, but that's a programming problem.  You can ask it here but it may not be the best forum.  If you do want to ask it here (or elsewhere), I'd suggest the following:  Write out, precisely, the rules you want to follow and clearly explain what tools you have available.